# Why am I getting a 403 error when I go to a site? Happens only from ONE of my computers

Tags: macos, firefox, google-chrome, apache-http-server

For the last couple days everytime I try to visit [Ticketmaster](http://ticketmaster.com) (happens for all urls of ticketmaster), I get a `403 forbidden: you don't have permission to access / on this server`. This only happens from my macbook pro. I can visit ticketmaster just fine from any other device on the same network (so its not like my ip is banned). I tried clearing my browser cache, cookies, etc. I tried Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rebooting your computer.  What you have described is weird and will be difficult to explain.

One possibility (but it is a bit of a long shot) is that Ticketmaster are going through a process of upgrading their servers as a result of "HeartBleed" - believe me System Admins are all scrambling at the moment - and one of their servers are down.

Its possible that its part of a cluster driven by DNS, and the DNS your MacBook has got for Ticketmaster is being reconfigured, where other systems are getting a different DNS answer and going to different machines.

Alternatively "wait a while and try again later" !!!!

Comment: Agree w/ the DNS comment.  Try to ping/dig/nslookup the TM hostname from the MBP.  Try that from a working device.  Are the IPs different?